# Is it possible to do fill forward with DataFrame.mul() fill_value?

Tags: python, pandas

Having 2 dataframes,

```
df
```

and

```
other
```

, with the same columns, I can see the `fill_value` argument to:

```
DataFrame.mul(other, fill_value=...)
```

has the following explanation:

```
fill_value : None or float value, default None
Fill missing (NaN) values with this value. If both DataFrame locations are missing, the result will be missing
```

How can I do the multiplication with a fill forward behavior, such  that for those rows in `df` that are not in `other`, I would fill forward the row in other, and still get a resulting row?

Here is an example:

`df`

```
1/1/2016 10
2/1/2016 20 
3/1/2016 25
```

`other`

```
1/1/2016 1.5
3/1/2016 1.7
```

I would want df.mul(other) to act as if other had

```
2/1/2016 1.5
```

as well

Comment: Can you show what example input and output dataframes would look like?

Comment: updated original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reindex `other` first:

```
df.mul(other.reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))
```

Example:

```
>>> df
             1
2016-01-01  10
2016-02-01  20
2016-03-01  25

>>> other
              1
2016-01-01  1.5
2016-03-01  1.7

>>> df.mul(other.reindex(df.index, method='ffill'))
               1
2016-01-01  15.0
2016-02-01  30.0
2016-03-01  42.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) or [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) with [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and then use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mul.html):

```
print df
             A
2016-01-01  10
2016-02-01  20
2016-03-01  25

print df1
              A
2016-01-01  1.5
2016-03-01  1.7

df1 = df1.reindex(df.index).fillna(method='ffill')
#df1 = df1.reindex_like(df).fillna(method='ffill')
print df1

              A
2016-01-01  1.5
2016-02-01  1.5
2016-03-01  1.7


print df.mul(df1)
               A
2016-01-01  15.0
2016-02-01  30.0
2016-03-01  42.5
```